# Python pdb on python script run as package

Tags: python, python-module, pdb

I have a python program that I usually run as a part of a package:

```
python -m mymod.client
```

in order to deal with relative imports inside "mymod/client.py." How do I run this with pdb - the python debugger. The following does not work:

```
python -m pdb mymod.client
```

It yields the error:

```
Error: mymod.client does not exist
```

### EDIT #1 (to address possible duplicity of question)

My question isn't really about running two modules simultaneously python, rather it is about how to use pdb on a python script that has relative imports inside it and which one usually deals with by running the script with "python -m."

Restated, my question could then be, how do I use pdb on such a script while not having to change the script itself just to have it run with pdb  (ie: preserving the relative imports inside the script as much as possible). Shouldn't this be possible, or am I forced to refactor in some way if I want to use pdb? If so what would be the minimal changes to the structure of the script that I'd have to introduce to allow me to leverage pdb.

In summary, I don't care *how* I run the script, just so long as I can get it working with pdb without changing it's internal structure (relative imports, etc) too much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple -m command line arguments (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423756/multiple-m-command-line-arguments-python)

Comment: @NathanielFord - see "Edit #1."

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Trying to convert my script to a package and not sure how to get -m pdb to work with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug a Python module from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265835/how-to-debug-a-python-module-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

I *think* I have a solution.

Run it like this:

```
python -m pdb path/mymod/client.py arg1 arg2
```

that will run it as a script, but will not treat it as a package. 
At the top of client.py, the first line should be:

```
import mymod
```

That will get the package itself loaded. 
I am still playing with this, but it seems to work so far.

Comment: you saved my day Skotch, especially with the importing of its own package. Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: One more thing though: In my case I had to append the working-dir where I'm launching the script to PYTHONPATH using `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:$(pwd)"`. Otherwise `import mymod` failed with a not-found error. I think python changes the working directory that gets inserted in sys.path to the directory that contains the script, rather than the directory where it is launched.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Though unstated in documentation, Python will not parse two modules via the `-m` command line option.