# How can i debug my code from the terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

How can i debug my python code step by step if i want to by placing the `red dots` from terminal as i used to do that on `PyCharm` but having difficulties with the debug when i run my file from the python terminal using the command

`python testings.py --annotations=input.csv`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug a Python module from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265835/how-to-debug-a-python-module-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I saw that and it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) for debugging using the command line.

It has a argument [b(reak)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break) that allows you to specify a line number where you want to have a break point.

It's definitely more cumbersome than using a proper IDE, but certainly helps in certain situations.

**Example:**

Simple example script (example.py):

```
a = 2
b = 5

c = a + b

print("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(a, b, c))
```

Starting debugger:

```
python3 -m pdb example.py
```

Now the debugger will start and will point to the first line. We can then use the commands (see documentation linked above) to step through the code. An example:

```
> /home/[...]/example.py(1)<module>()
-> a = 2
(Pdb) b 4
Breakpoint 1 at /home/[...]/example.py:4
(Pdb) c
> /home/[...]/example.py(4)<module>()
-> c = a + b
(Pdb) s
> /home/[...]/example.py(6)<module>()
-> print("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(a, b, c))
(Pdb) p c
7
(Pdb)
```

Explanation: Every line with `(Pdb)` is a prompt where you can enter commands. Here are the commands I entered:

1. `b 4` sets a breakpoint at line 4. This is confirmed by the next line.
2. `c` continues running the script until the next breakpoint is hit. As you can see in the next line, the debugger now stops at `c = a + b` which is line 4 of the script.
3. `s` performs one step, so we are now at the print statement.
4. `p c` prints the value of expression "c" which in this case is simply the value of the variable `c`: 7

For more commands and their explanations, again, take  look at the official documentation. Hope this serves as a very basic introduction on how to use Pdb.

Comment: interesting can you add a small example of how to specify lines