# pdb unable to use from currentdir import mod

Tags: python, pdb

Here is the current directory setup:

```
dir_a:
  __init__.py
  one.py
  two.py
```

Here is one.py:

```
from dir_a.two import TwoClass
```

From inside dir_a, running

```
"python -m pdb one.py"
```

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir_a'"
```

From inside pdb, I've tried appending the absolute path to dir_a, but still having trouble finding and being able to import my Two class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pdb on python script run as package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227688/python-pdb-on-python-script-run-as-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. From directory containing dir_a:
   `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:$(pwd)"`
2. In pdb: `import sys; sys.path.append('[dir containing dir_a]')`

Don't add the `dir_a` path itself.